# Timer on android

Tags: android, timer, nullpointerexception, handler, delay

I am making a program that has a timer in it. I have this code. The program is forced to close after the start button is clicked. but if i make >myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0); 
a comment, the program will run, but the timer in the program will not. WHAT IS WRONG WITH MY CODE???

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textTimer;
private Handler myHandler;
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;
private long startTime = 0L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ingame.class);
            startActivity(nextScreen);
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0); // if i make this line of code a comment, the program will run but without a timer
        }
    });
}

    private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

            int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
            textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
```

}

**UPDATED logcat**

```
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at com.example.reactiontime.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:50)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-04 01:53:28.103: E/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.reactiontime"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.reactiontime.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ingame"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?? what kind of errors are you getting at the time of crashing??

Comment: The Handler instance was never created.

Comment: From the stack trace:
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.reactiontime/com.example.reactiontime.ingame}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: post your `manifest.xml`.

Comment: @HamidShatu I edited the post with the manifest in it.

Comment: `textTimer` is obviously null from your code.

Comment: but so is `myHandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line...

```
private Handler myHandler;
```

to...

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

You forgot to initialize your `muHandler` object. Initialize it.

**Update:**

why did you put `this` in the following line inside your thread???

```
myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
```

Here, `this` means the current `Acitivity`'s context. Comment out the above line as below...I think your problem will be solved.

```
private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        //myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

**Another Update:**

Initialize your `TextView` name `textTimer` in `onCreate()` method as below...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);

    //initializ as below
    textTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
}
```

When you are trying set text to that `TextView`, it can't find any `TextView`.

Comment: I already declared the ingame.java in the manifest.xml but still the program is forced to close after the start button is clicked

Comment: still the same, "force close"

Comment: which line is the 50th line in your `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: >textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
this line

Comment: of course, why did I miss that part. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
myHandler = new Handler();
```

before the problematic row of code.

EDIT after stack trace added:

From the stack trace: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.reactiontime/com.example.reactiontime.ingame}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Check if you declared the activity in you manifest file.